# Python 3 output not making any sense compiling programme "Working with queues" from the book "Beginning programming with python for dummies"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import queue
MyQueue = queue.Queue(3)
print(MyQueue.empty())
input("Press any key when ready...")
MyQueue.put(1)
MyQueue.put(2)
print(MyQueue.full())
input("Press any key when ready...")
MyQueue.put(3)
print(MyQueue.full())
input("Press any key when ready...")
print(MyQueue.get())
print(MyQueue.empty())
print(MyQueue.full())
input("Press any key when ready...")
print(MyQueue.get())
print(MyQueue.get())
```

Hi, I am coding Python 3 using Jupypter notebook, recently, I have been programming according to the book "Beginning programming with python for dummies third edition" and came across this programme titled "Working with queues" (code as above), but I am not getting the expected output as the book.
This is what I have been getting.

[image]

Can anyone explains why this is happening and how to solve it?

The image is what I am getting on my laptop, the following is what is printed on the book:

```
True
Press any key when ready...
1
False
False

Press any key when ready...
{Box for entering stuff}
```

Comment: "I am not getting the expected output as the book" - so, what's the expected output?

Comment: I suspect the "expected" output is what he prevously had in the link (before the post was edited - now it's the image). 

I'm more curious about the actual output.

Comment: @geo I think the image is the actual output, not expected

Comment: Your output looks pretty much what I'd expect. Unless you should *exactly* what is in the book (not some phrased summary), we can't really help you finding the misunderstanding with the book.

Comment: Make sure your python version is the same as the book's python version. I'm not positive but perhaps the queue library has changed since whenever that book was written and that would explain the unwanted output.

Comment: I just put the expected output from the book. Plus my version of python is 3.6 i think